# InstallShield 2009 different shortcut icon for different releases

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2009

I have an InstallShield 2009 MSI project with a couple of shortcuts. I would like to change which icon is used for these shortcuts depending on the release.  Each release is for a separate country (and therefore language), and some have a different icon.  Is it possible to do this and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas for approaches; neither is perfect. First, since you indicate different languages, it may be best to separate these shortcuts into a component per language. Then you can use the Languages setting on the component in conjunction with a language selection on each release to filter down to the one you want.

The second approach is much looser and is probably unmaintainable without an automated build process. You could carefully tweak the path variable reference used by the shortcut's icon, and override the value used for that path variable in each build. Thus each build would reference a different file.

You may also want to check out the MUI options if you can take on a Windows Installer 4.0/4.5 dependency, but I don't see icon support there. The MUI support lets you specify a resource index into a DLL which will be used to pull the appropriate language's value. But these are just for Display Name and Description equivalents.